# VB.NET - How to use array literal in a condition?

Tags: vb.net, arrays, conditional-statements, literals

I just learn how to create an array literal in VB.NET.

```
Dim MyArray = New Integer() { 1, 2, 3 }
' Or
Dim MyArray() As Integer = { 1, 2, 3 }
' Or
Dim MyArray() = { 1, 2, 3 }
' Or
Dim MyArray() = { 1, 2, "A", "B" }
```

Now, I want to use A LITERAL ARRAY in a condition (see pseudo-code)

```
If 1 exists in {1,2,3,4} Then
    MsgBox "Exists!"
End If
```

but I don't know how, seems like you have to assign it to a variable before you can use it in the condition.

```
    Dim MyArray() As Integer = {3, 2, 3}
    If (MyArray.Contains(1)) Then
        MsgBox("exists!")
    Else
        MsgBox("does not exist!")
    End If
```

The above code works, but I'm just wondering is there any way to do this without assigning the array literal to variable first?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `{1,2,3,4}.Contains(1)` for this.

Comment: I didn't know it will work! :) Maybe the code looks so uncommon so I have not tried. I also tried this `(New Integer() {3, 1, 3}).Contains(1)` its more elegant. Thanks!

Comment: If the answer was a snake, I could have been killed by it, its already in front of me!