# How Can I Pass a Time Series to NDtw Using VB.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, f#, dtw

I would like to use the NDtw nuget package to compare two simple time series.  The following code works in F# and is published at (https://www.codesuji.com/2016/12/13/F-and-Dynamic-Time-Warping/).

```
open NDtw

// Example comparison of 2 small datasets
let exampleDtw = new Dtw(
    [| 1.; 3.; 7.; 8.; 11.;  6.; 6.; |],
    [| 3.; 6.; 3.; 7.; 13.; 12.; 7.; |])


// Get the coordinate path used for the best match between the datasets
let output = exampleDtw.GetCost()

printf "%A" output
```

It works in F# but I want to be able to use the library in VB.net.  The library also works in C# so it should also be able to be used in VB.net or any of the .net languages.  The problem is that I cannot figure out what format the time series data should be in.  The library contains a Class called SeriesVariable but I cannot figure out how that variable should be formatted.  The format from the F# example does not work.  Below is my code.  I have tried square brackets, parentheses, adding commas, adding colon, etc.

```
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim dist As Int16

        Dim dtw As New Dtw([| 1.; 3.; 7.; 8.; 11.;  6.; 6.; |],[| 3.; 6.; 3.; 7.; 13.; 12.; 7.; |])

        dist = dtw.GetCost()

        TextBox3.Text = dist.ToString

    End Sub
```

How can I get this code to work?

Comment: If you look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5341030/f-collection-initializer-syntax, you'll see that the `Dtw` constructor is taking two floating point (likely `double`) arrays. VB has a syntax for literal arrays (that I can never remember). Just use it. Here's an example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907002/vb-net-how-to-use-array-literal-in-a-condition

Comment: @Flydog57 The VB array syntax is curly braces `{` and `}` bracketing the comma-separated sequence of members.

Comment: It's been >10 years since I used VB.  It seems to me, you had to do something like `Double() {1.0, 2.0}` back then, not just `{1.0, 2.0}`.  But, it's been a long time.

Comment: This ended up working.  Thanks to both of you. 
        Dim series1() As Double = {1.0, 3.0, 7.0, 8.0, 11.0, 6.0, 6.0}